# Normalize vector field by NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have array `field` of shape [height width 2]
And i want to make lenght of every [i, j] less or equal 1
I use following procedure to do it

```
def projectionOntoDisc(var):
    res = np.zeros_like(var)
    for i in xrange(var.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(var.shape[1]):
            norm = max(1.0, np.linalg.norm(var[i, j]))
            res[i, j] = var[i, j] / norm
    return res
```

Is there way to do it faster?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorise this operation, which should increase execution speed bu several orders of magnitude:

```
norm = numpy.fmax(1.0, numpy.linalg.norm(var, axis=2))
res = var / norm[:, :, numpy.newaxis]
```

Comment: Maybe i can combine this with pointwise maximum to achive norm = max(1.0, np.linalg.norm(var[i, j]))

Comment: @Dark_Daiver: Sorry, I missed the max bit at first — now added to my answer.

Comment: No problem. Thank you again. My algo now works significantly faster =)